# Shortcut to insert comments on TextMate?

Tags: php, html, textmate, coda

In Coda I can make a selection (of code) and press Cmd+/ and it will comment it. If I'm in an HTML section it will use `<!-- -->` and if I'm in a PHP section it will use `/* */`.

I enjoyed this but didn't realize how much until I switched to TextMate and lost the functionality. Is there an easy way to do the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the functionality in the bundles under `Source` - `Comments`:
[image]

At least on my (German) keyboard the following works: <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>/</kbd>, because the <kbd>/</kbd> is only available by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>7</kbd>. I can't *really* speak for other keyboards, but I guess <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>/</kbd> should therefore work on US ones, as the shortcut is the same.

Comment: It does work using `Cmd-/` on international layouts.

Comment: great - thanks! i had another program conflicting with that key but after disabling it it started working great! :)